# Replace '-' with '--' in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to replace a single dash '-' character in a string with double dashes.

```
2015–09–01T16:00:00.000Z

to be

2015-–09-–01T16:00:00.000Z
```

This is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var temp = '2015–09–01T16:00:00.000Z'
temp.replace(/-/g,'--')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In JavaScript Strings are immutable. So, when you modify a string, a new string object will be created with the modification.

In your case, the `replace` has replaced the characters but returns a new string. You need to store that in a variable to use it.

For example,

```
var temp = '2015–09–01T16:00:00.000Z';
temp = temp.replace(/–/g,'--');
```

---

**Note** The string which you have shown in the question, when copied, I realised that it is a [different character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) but looks similar to `–` and it is not the same as hyphen (`-`). The character codes for those characters are as follows

```
console.log('–'.charCodeAt(0));
// 8211: en dash
console.log('-'.charCodeAt(0));
// 45: hyphen
```

Comment: Not only in JavaScript but nearly in all major languages string variables are immutable.

Answer (score 7):

The hyphen character `–` you have in the string is different from the one you have in the RegExp `-`. Even though they look alike, they are different characters.

The correct RegExp in this case is `temp.replace(/–/g,'--')`

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest thing would be to just use split and join.

```
var temp = '2015–09–01T16:00:00.000Z'.split("-").join("--");
```

Comment: As explained in other answers, this should work only when the character you're splitting by is same as used in the string.